# perspective transformation in Python: from rectangular to trapezoid

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, projection, geometry-surface

I am looking for a python function or library that can convert coordinates of rectangle to trapezoid coordinates. So far I found the relevant problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/mapping-irregular-quadrilateral-to-a-rectangle but no code is available. Is there any package or any function in Python that can do this?

Comment: "trapezoid coordinates" is not a common phrase: I find no definition of that in Bing or Google. Please tell us here what you mean, rather than making us look at another question to understand what you are asking--especially since the other question never clarified the exact meaning. Are you looking for an affine transformation that transforms a given trapezoid to a given rectangle?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Are you looking for a perspective transform ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674433/Perspective-Projection-of-a-Rectangle-Homography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to do the same but from trapezoid to rectangular coordinated. The package that do the trick is:

```
from skimage.transform import ProjectiveTransform
```

You can read the complete answer in:

[Transform irregular quadrilateral to rectangle in python matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283088/transform-irregular-quadrilateral-to-rectangle-in-python-matplotlib)