# How to align image for OCR ? How to know the rotation angle to align image to horizontal axis?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

[image]

[image]

I am trying to align the image along the horizontal axis to improve the accuracy of OCR. Image was cropped after taking predictions from SSD object detection algorithm. Kindly tell me some code or procedure to align them horizontally to perform better OCR.

[image]

I tried feature based image alignment but could not get the satisfactory results. Could you tell me any method for it?

My goal is to align images like this horizontally to perform the OCR properly, for that I guess I have to know at what angle to rotate the image.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Adnan, welcome to StackOverflow! Rotating the image taken at this angle wouldn't be sufficient as it will still be deformed. Skewing is the correct approach. Try to calculate where the corners of the image are and then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303869/1901114 for how to skew image once you know the coordinates.

Comment: Hi,, thanks for your reply.,, how can i calculate the corners of image for projective transform ?@Mirac7

Comment: Have you tried with a simple google search ? For example this [deskew image](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/) could help you..

Comment: @Link unfortunately it didnt help because i guess my image isnt entirely consisted of text...

Comment: @AdnanSharif can you proceed with this step ? Binarize your image (threshold), add some borders (10-15 pixel should be enough) and do the same script again ? These just to know if there is any improvement..

Or, better, can you post the code you worked on by now ?

Thanks

Comment: @Link i just tried borders on the image and then applied feature based image alignment using a reference image as in this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/ and it works fine now but still i will have to perform tests on multiple images... anyways thanks for your help and idea. This was my first time to post question on stackoverflow and i cant believe how much helpfull the community is.

Comment: I will post also a code in a few minutes, based on PyImageSearch example, which seems to work. Please, from your side, post some other images to test.

P.S: not all community is kind like this ;)

Comment: @Link I have added few more pictures,, image alignment using reference image probably works fine but if the reference format is little bit different, it sometimes maligns it.

Comment: i would really appreciate if you can post the code for it.